# Transfer folder from server a to b

Tags: linux, ssh, zip

I have a local virtual machine with **Debian** and want to move a folder from there to my external hosted server. The problem is that the folder size is never the same after transfer.

I already tried to zip the folder on local machine. Move to my **windows** host via **ssh** and then copy the zip via ssh to the external server. But afer unziping the results are the following

```
Local machine
    root@debian:/var/www/html/zip_test# du -sh test_symfony/
    95M     test_symfony/

External Server
    (uiserver):u94465931:~/zip_est$ du -sh test_symfony/
    88M     test_symfony/
```

Another method I tried was to copy the folder to the external server without zip. With following result:

```
    (uiserver):u94465931:~$ du -sh test_symfony/
    92M     test_symfony/
```

So I am not able to get the full 95M to my external server. Could you please give me an advice? I want to be sure that any file was transfered.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Any error messages during unzipping? Enough space on the device? Otherwise, do something like `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c '%n %s' * | sort` on both machines, then `diff` to see which files have different sizes or are missing. Investigate how this happens, e.g. by comparing files with different size, only putting a few of these files into the zip, etc.

Comment: Compute the MD5 checksum of the archive (the "zip file") locally and after transfer. If it's the same, then the size difference is due to filesystem-specific differences.

Comment: There was no error while unzipping. The MD5 checksum is the same. I couldn't find any file which does not exist on the external server. So seems really causes by filesystem specific differernces. I was trying to avoid something like this and installed the same debian version on both systems.